# Call my Camera- application from another(ex. messenger)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-manifest

I'd like to see my camera application in selection box, when I try to open camera from another application (for example messenger).
How can I catch the camera intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an `<intent-filter>` on your camera activity like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and follow the rest of [the documented rules for the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#action_image_capture) (e.g., `EXTRA_OUTPUT`).